# What code in the OpenSSL sources contains the FREAK vulnerability?

Tags: windows, security, openssl

There is an issue in the code found in `s3_clnt.c`. I'm trying to determine what library this code ends up getting built to. Is it libeay32/64 or ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

> I'm trying to determine what library this code ends up getting built to. Is it libeay32/64 or ?

On Linux, the output executable `libssl.{a|so}`. On Windows, everything goes into `libeay` (IIRC).